# preg_match with UTF8

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

Let's say I have the following:

```
$str1 = "via Tokyo";
$str2 = "via 東京";
```

I want to match any non-whitespace characters after the "via ". Normally I'd use the following:

```
preg_match("/via\s(\S+)/", $str2, $match);
```

to obtain the matching characters. I assumed this wouldn't work with the above due to `preg_match` not understanding utf8, however it works perfectly in this case.

Is this working correctly because `preg_match` is simply looking for bytes that *aren't* whitespace, and if so, am I safe to use this for any UTF8 characters?

PS I'm aware that I should really be using the `mb_ereg` functions for this (or avoiding PHP altogether) but I'm looking for a better understanding of why this works. Thanks!

Comment: It "works", but it will consider `U+2003 EM SPACE`, `U+200A HAIR SPACE`, and other characters with the `Space` property to be non-space (`\S`) instead of space (`\s`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, UTF-8 uses multi-byte sequences for the special Unicode characters, and it guarantees that they are different from the ASCII ones by having a high bit (undermore). So searching for slash, backslash or space will never have a false positive in a multi-byte sequence.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification regarding the guarantee of no false-positives.

Answer (score 0):

It's working because the individual bytes that make up `東` and `京` happen to not be whitespace characters in the single-byte character set. Among other things, your regex would happilly accept - - (em space) despite it being a whitespace character.

Try adding the `u` modifier to the end, to enable UTF-8 support.